# Background-color of div or section is not changing properly or or not even a bit

Tags: html, css, frontend, mobile-website

```css
.forBackground {
  background-color: white;
}

.kontaktUndMapContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.überschriftKontakt {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.überschriftKontakt2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Tor {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.kontaktUndMap {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.kontakt {
  list-style: none;
}

.kontaktieren {
  color: #2994D1;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="forBackground">
  <div>
    <h1 class="Galerie1">Neuliche Vollfolierungen</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img class="img1" src="/Images/SKlasse2 (1).png" alt="Bild" style="max-width:100%;height:auto; ">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="img2" src="/Images/image (1).png" alt="Bild" style="max-width:100%;height:auto; ">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="img3" src="/Images/MercedesSeiteGrau (2) (1).jpg" alt="Bild" style="max-width:100%;height:auto; ">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</section>
<section class="forBackground">
  <div class="kontaktUndMapContainer" id="Kontakt">
    <div class="kontaktUndMap">
      <h1 class="überschriftKontakt">Kontakt &amp; Standort </h1>
      <ul class="kontakt">
        <li>Autofolierung-Camellion</li>
        <li>Cecil-Taylor-Ring 12-18, <span class="Tor">Tor 13</span></li>
        <li>68309 Mannheim</li>
        <h2 class="überschriftKontakt2">Kontakt</h2>
        <li><a class="kontaktieren" href="tel:+491575 0167818">01575 0167818</a></li>
        <li><a class="kontaktieren" href="mailto:Camellion-ma@outlook.de">Camellion-ma@outlook.de</a></li>
        <li><a class="kontaktieren" href="https://www.instagram.com/autofolierung_camellion/?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y%3D">Instagram</a></li>
        <h2 class="überschriftKontakt2">Öffnungszeiten</h2>
        <li>Montag - Freitag</li>
        <li>10:00 Uhr - 18:00 Uhr</li>
        <li>Samstag u. Sonntag</li>
        <li>Geschlossen</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="kontaktUndMap">
    <iframe class="karte" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d82890.4294379866!2d8.396214735264484!3d49.516122362531995!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4797cfff559df73d%3A0x9cbecc6d734f240c!2sAutofolierung-Camellion!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1664298642367!5m2!1sde!2sde"
      width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

These two divs need to have a white background; If I put them in the same section the background won't change a bit. If I set the background-color of the divs in the "kontaktUndMapContainer" class there will be some black spots on the left and under the map like you see on the image I uploaded. I have set the background-color of the page to black. So the notch on iPhones will be black and not white. I can't find any CSS properties that block this...

Comment: your question is not clear. I can see no image here. Also which two divs are you talking about specifically? Be clear, so that others can understand and help you better

Answer (score -2):

the .forBackground thing isn't in a  tag.